# How to load the text in button dynamically based on the store value in sencha?

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a button:

```
               {
                    xtype:'button',
                    text:'2',
                    ui: 'orange',
                    style: 'font-size:14px;',
                    height:20

                }
```

I want the text of the button to be loaded dynamically depending on the number of priority values in the store.
If the priority value is 0 for ten values i want the button text as 10. Can anyone help me regarding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`setText()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Button-method-setText) method of `Ext.Button`. That will dynamically set the `text` for your button.

First, set the `id` property on your button

```
{
  xtype:'button',
  text:'2',
  id: 'myBtn',
  ui: 'orange',
  style: 'font-size:14px;',
  height:20
 }
```

Then do like this,

```
  if(validCondition) {
      Ext.getCmp('myBtn').setText('10');
  }
```

*`validCondition` is the condition that you want to set before changing the text.